# Fortran OpenMP function not increasing speed increasing threads beyond 2

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

I have been stuck trying to get a specific function I have written in `fortran` to work as fast as I think it should in parallel with `openmp`. This is compiled with `gfortran-10`, with the following (excessive for some) flags

```
gfortran-10 test.f08 -O2 -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra -Wunused-dummy-argument -Wconversion -Wconversion-extra -Wintrinsic-shadow -Wsurprising  -fbacktrace -fbounds-check -fcheck=all
```

As a side note, I have tried compiling with less runtime flags and other `-O` options but none have helped. Essentially the function just computes one large sum and I am simply making the first loop in parallel. The indexing on the arrays is not the issue, but for clarity the `u` and `v` arrays are of size `4*N_x*N_y*N_m*N_g`. Typical values of these variables are

```
N_x=N_y=10, N_m=150, N_g=20
```

What follows is `test.f08` containing a program that reproduces the issue I am having, the function of issue being `INNER_PRODUCT`:

```
MODULE IP_ROUTINES

IMPLICIT NONE

CONTAINS

!==================================================
!
!==================================================
SUBROUTINE GENERATE_INNER_PROD(IP_Mat, Basis_Mat, Area, N_x, N_y, N_m, N_g, rank, Open_Threads)

  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL*8,INTENT(OUT):: IP_Mat(*)
  REAL*8,INTENT(IN):: Basis_Mat(*)
  REAL*8,INTENT(IN):: Area(*)
  INTEGER,INTENT(IN):: N_x, N_y, N_m, N_g, rank, Open_Threads

  INTEGER:: solve_time1, solve_time2, clockrate
  REAL*8:: solve_time

  INTEGER:: i, j, k
  INTEGER:: basis_len
  INTEGER:: b_p(rank)
  LOGICAL:: Identity
  Identity = .TRUE.

  WRITE(*,*) "GENERATING INNER PRODUCT MATRIX"
  CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(solve_time1)

  !length of a single vector
  basis_len = 4*N_x*N_y*N_m*N_g

  b_p(1) = 1
  DO i = 2, rank
    b_p(i) = b_p(i-1) + basis_len !points to first index of i-th vector
  END DO

  k = 1
  DO i = 1, rank
  write(*,*) i
    DO j = 1, rank

      !calculate B(j,i) = <b_j, b_i>_w
      IP_Mat(k) = INNER_PRODUCT(Basis_Mat(b_p(j)), Basis_Mat(b_p(i)), Area, N_x, N_y, N_m, N_g, Open_Threads)

      k = k + 1

    END DO
  END DO

  CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(solve_time2,clockrate)
  solve_time=(DBLE(solve_time2)-DBLE(solve_time1))/DBLE(clockrate)
  WRITE(*,'(A,ES16.8,A)') "     Solve took ",solve_time," seconds."

END SUBROUTINE GENERATE_INNER_PROD

!==================================================
!
!==================================================
REAL*8 FUNCTION INNER_PRODUCT(u, v, Area, N_x, N_y, N_m, N_g, Open_Threads)

  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL*8,INTENT(IN):: u(*), v(*)
  REAL*8,INTENT(IN):: Area(*)
  INTEGER,INTENT(IN):: N_x, N_y, N_m, N_g, Open_Threads

  INTEGER:: i, j, m, g, Threads
  INTEGER:: A_p, gm_len, ij_len
  INTEGER:: left, right, bot, top
  INTEGER:: bot_left, bot_right, top_left, top_right
  REAL*8:: w, ip
  REAL*8,ALLOCATABLE:: ip_(:)

  ALLOCATE(ip_(N_g))
  ij_len = 4*N_x*N_y

  !$ Threads = Open_Threads
  !$ IF (Threads .GT. N_g) Threads = N_g
  !$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED) NUM_THREADS(Threads) PRIVATE(i, j, m, g, A_p, left, right, bot, top, bot_left, bot_right, &
  !$OMP top_left, top_right, w, ip, gm_len)
  !$OMP DO
  DO g = 1, N_g
    ip = 0d0
    gm_len = (g-1)*4*N_x*N_y*N_m
    DO m = 1, N_m

      A_p = 1
      DO j = 1, N_y
        DO i = 1, N_x

          left = 2*i-1
          right = 2*i
          bot = 2*j-1
          top = 2*j

          bot_left  = left  + (bot-1)*2*N_x + gm_len
          bot_right = right + (bot-1)*2*N_x + gm_len
          top_left  = left  + (top-1)*2*N_x + gm_len
          top_right = right + (top-1)*2*N_x + gm_len

          w = Area(A_p)

          ip = ip + u(bot_left)  * v(bot_left)  * w
          ip = ip + u(bot_right) * v(bot_right) * w
          ip = ip + u(top_left)  * v(top_left)  * w
          ip = ip + u(top_right) * v(top_right) * w

          A_p = A_p + 1
        END DO
      END DO

      gm_len = gm_len + ij_len
    END DO
    ip_(g) = ip
  END DO
  !$OMP END DO
  !$OMP END PARALLEL

  INNER_PRODUCT = SUM(ip_)
  DEALLOCATE(ip_)

END FUNCTION INNER_PRODUCT

END MODULE IP_ROUTINES

!==================================================
!
!==================================================
program main

    USE IP_ROUTINES

    IMPLICIT NONE
    
    REAL*8,ALLOCATABLE:: IP_Mat(:), Basis_Mat(:), Area(:)
    INTEGER:: N_x, N_y, N_m, N_g, rank, Open_Threads
    
    N_x = 10
    N_y = 10
    N_m = 150
    N_g = 20
    rank = 250
    Open_Threads = 20
    
    ALLOCATE(IP_Mat(rank*rank))
    ALLOCATE(Basis_Mat(4*N_x*N_y*N_m*N_g*rank))
    ALLOCATE(Area(N_x*N_y))
    
    Basis_Mat = 1d0
    Area = 1d0
    
    CALL GENERATE_INNER_PROD(IP_Mat, Basis_Mat, Area, N_x, N_y, N_m, N_g, rank, Open_Threads)
    
    DEALLOCATE(IP_Mat)
    DEALLOCATE(Basis_Mat)
    DEALLOCATE(Area)


end
```

On my machine (windows 10, but running the code with ubuntu using the windows linux subsystem) the subroutine `GENERATE_INNER_PROD` runs in roughly 70 seconds using 1 thread, and roughly 50 seconds using 2 threads. However, adding any more threads after the second yields very small amounts of extra speedup, not going past about 45 seconds even up to 20 threads. The vectors `u` and `v` are given as sections of the large array `Basis_Mat` which is of size `4*N_x*N_y*N_m*N_g*rank`. In the case of my tests this translates to 300 million elements in `Basis_Mat`.

I have attempted openmp on the loops over `rank` in the `GENERATE_INNER_PROD` subroutine, but this actually yields slower results. I'm somewhat convinced the problem is coming from some sort of bottleneck in accessing elements of `Basis_Mat` but so far this hasn't gotten me anywhere. I have tried copying `Basis_Mat` and calling the function like

```
IP_Mat(k) = INNER_PRODUCT(Basis_Mat_copy(b_p(j)), Basis_Mat(b_p(i)), Area, N_x, N_y, N_m, N_g, Open_Threads)
```

but this did not yield any different results. I did notice that when the function is called only with the `b_p(i)` index like

```
IP_Mat(k) = INNER_PRODUCT(Basis_Mat(b_p(i)), Basis_Mat(b_p(i)), Area, N_x, N_y, N_m, N_g, Open_Threads)
```

the code moves blisteringly fast, but of course this is probably due to compiler optimization since the call no longer depends on `j`. At the end of the day, I don't understand how to fix the scaling issue, it seems like code that should benefit from adding more threads. Furthermore, I have identified for sure that the issue comes from usage of the `u` and `v` arrays, as simply setting `ip=1` lets the code run much faster.

Comment: Performance is very difficult to debug without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the very, very least please tell us the typical values of N_m, N_x and N_y

Comment: Oh, and also not enough flags for me! -std=f2018 would be another good one

Comment: Sorry about the typos, I corrected ```SCB_INNER_PRODUCT``` to the regular function title @francescalus

Comment: I also added values for those variables, usually it would be something like N_x=N_y=10, N_m=150, N_g=20. Sorry about that! @IanBush

Comment: Are you always specifying the `-fcheck=all` option?  This one will slow your code down.  You can get a sense of what is being optimized with the `-fopt-info` and/or `-fopt-info-all` options.  You may also want to investigate the `-ftree-vectorize` and `-funroll-loops --param max-unroll-times=4` options.  Adjust 4 as needed.

Comment: -fbounds-check, included in -fcheck=all, has a run-time cost, as indicated in the previous comment.   This check is extremely useful in debugging, but is normally removed in production code.   I've found that in many programs the penalty is small, but if you are concerned with run-time speed, omit these.

Comment: The question seems to me to be more about parallel scaling, rather than raw execution time. As such slow execution caused by -fcheck=all should actually improve the scalability, as the parallel overheads are, as a percentage, smaller. Thus while I don't disagree that for production runs -fhceck=all should be omitted I don't think it is relevant here.

Comment: @jmcoale Let's ask the obvious - you do have more than two cores in your machine?

Comment: @steve Thanks for the tip, I'm planning on investigating those flags once I am back at my machine.

Comment: @M.S.B. Yeah I have attempted removing the flags that would slow the program down on runtime to see if that helped but to no avail, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Also @IanBush can confirm I have access to 32 cores on my machine :)

Comment: OK, in that case without a minimal reproducible example, as mentioned in the first comment, it's going to be hard to make progress. If you can't provide one I suggest you get out your favourite profiler, throw it at your code, and see what that can tell you.

Comment: @IanBush thanks for your (and others) patience, I'm still getting used to the format of the site. As of yet I am still unsure what the problem is after a few more days of debugging but have made an attempt to put together a minimal example that reproduces my issue.

Comment: OK, many thanks, much appreciated that you have put this effort in. On my 4 core machine I see the times on 1, 2, 3, and 4 threads as 111.98, 64.01, 58.75 and 57.34 seconds respectively, which looks consistent with what you report. Will have a think later or tomorrow.

Comment: @jmcoale Is there a good reason you are not parallelising over the double loop of size rank  in `GENERATE_INNER_PROD`? And do you know about reductions in OpenMP?

Comment: @IanBush I have attempted parallelizing over the rank loops, but this didn't give any gains in performance for me. I also know very little about array reduction, although I did end up reading on it a little during my own debugging so I am somewhat acquainted with it.